# Expose a service in a Kubernetes cluster to the outside using Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl, minikube, nginx-ingress

I need to expose a service to the outside using Ingress on an EC2 instance. I have three services running in the Kubernetes cluster, one of them must be accessible from outside, the other two only communicate internally with the first. To expose the service I am trying to use Ingress, but I am a little confused with the necessary configurations and the way Ingress works.

What I have tried:

***deployment.yaml***

```
### DEPLOYMENTS ###


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: agify-deployment
  labels:
    app: agify
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: agify
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: agify
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: agify
        image: myrepo/svc_agify:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9010

---


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: genderize-deployment
  labels:
    app: genderize
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: genderize
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: genderize
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: genderize
        image: myrepo/svc_genderize:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9020

---


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: core-deployment
  labels:
    app: core
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: core
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: core
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: core
        image: myrepo/svc_core:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9030

---

### SERVICES ###

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: agify-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: agify
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9010

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: genderize-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: genderize
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9020

---

# CORE SERVICE

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: core-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: core
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9030
  type: NodePort

---

# INGRESS

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
   name: ingress-core
   annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
   rules:
   - host: my-service.com
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
             name: core-svc
             port:
               number: 80
```

In my /etc/hosts file on the EC2 instance I have placed the following so that my-service.com resolves to the minikube IP address.

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX my-service.com
```

If I try it within the EC2 instance where I have the cluster, it works perfectly. But how do I consume the service from outside the EC2 instance? What is lacking?

To clarify, I already have the inbound and outbound rules configured on my EC2 instance.

I found that I need to add the following configuration to the Ingress resource, but the configuration seems to be invalid

```
spec:
    ingressClassName: nginx
    loadBalancerIP: xx.xx.xx.xx # EC2 instance public IP
```

​

Comment: I think, either use nodeport to expose the service to be available outside of cluster or create ingress and expose your service to access through load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify your question if you are using ingress to expose the service you don't need to specify NodePort this will be security violation. You should use only the cluster IP. If you are not providing the service type default it will take CluterIP. To answer your question yes there is no ingressClassName has been specified in the ingress I have updated your ingress yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-core
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
 ingressClassName: nginx
 rules:
  - host: my-service.com
    http:
     paths:
     - path: /
       pathType: Prefix
       backend:
        service:
         name: core-svc
         port:
           number: 80
```

Make sure to do the proper indentation it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `core-svc` service is currently of type `NodePort,` it's already accessible from outside the cluster using the public IP of your EC2 instance and the assigned `NodePort` port number. However, for more seamless external access, consider changing the service type to `LoadBalancer`. This will provision an external load balancer, like an Elastic Load Balancer on AWS, and expose your service externally. Additionally, setting `loadBalancerIP` in the Ingress resource might not be supported by all cloud providers and could lead to unexpected behavior.

To expose your Kubernetes service to the outside world using Ingress on an EC2 instance:

1. Deploy an Ingress controller in your Kubernetes cluster. You can use
   a Helm chart for this purpose. Refer to the NGINX Ingress Controller
   documentation for details on how it works: [NGINX Ingress Controller
   Documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/).

   Ensure that the service you want to expose `core-svc` is of type
   `ClusterIP`. It should not be `NodePort` if you're using Ingress.